# How to know when passenger rolling restart is finished?

Tags: passenger

If I configure rolling restarts in enterprise passenger and then touch restart.txt, how do I check programmatically whether the process has been completed and can be guaranteed the old version is no longer being served?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the question was asked, but here is a piece of answer for others who, like me, found this question while googling:

When you do a "touch tmp/restart.txt", you can check passenger processes status using the command:

```
    rvmsudo passenger-status
```

You'll then see some processes with a "rolling restart" line under them. 
When it is finished you can also check the uptime of each passenger processes (using the same command).

Of course as you just restarted the passenger application, the uptime should be a couple seconds when the whole rolling restart is completed. This should be a proof that your application restarted correctly and uses the new version.

Finally if you want to be really really sure that your application uses the new version, you could just add a "version number" of your application in one of your views (maybe in your administration view or a secret view or in the legals of your website...).

You could use capistrano to automatically increment the version each time you deploy. (But if you use capistrano you don't need this 'version control' I think ;-) ).